# In Mui x datepicker how can i set popper direction of Datepicker?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

My Datepicker always pops in the bottom left of my input.
how can I change the direction of the calendar icon instead?
I have tried for many hours

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx2B7.png)

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
            <DatePicker
              sx={{
                width: 453,
                marginBottom: 5,
                "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
                  height: 48,
                  borderRadius: "0.5rem",
                  border: "1px solid #CBD5E0",
                },
              }}
              components={{
                OpenPickerIcon: () => (
                  <img
                    src={calendarIcon}
                    alt="Calendar Icon"
                    className="w-[24px] h-[24px] mx-[4px]"
                  />
                ),
              }}
              format="DD-MM-YYYY"
            />
          </LocalizationProvider>
```

How can I change the direction to the calendar icon instead?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datepicker has a prop `slotProps`  - documentation https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#DatePicker-prop-slotProps
So you use `slotProps` prop to override the `popper` component and change the `placement` per your choice - check the available placement options here: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/popper/#Popper-prop-placement

e.g.

```
<DatePicker label="Basic date picker" slotProps={{ popper: { placement: 'bottom-end' }}}/>
```

Comment: thank you very much! that's help

in addition
how can i custom datepicker input or calendar
example focus,border in Input, size of calendar or bg color?